# warning: passing argument 1 of 'evenOrOdd' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

Incompatible pointer type but I don't understand that it exactly means. Here's the error: "warning: passing argument 1 of 'evenOrOdd' from incompatible pointer type"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isEven(int x)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        return x;
    }
}

int isOdd(int x)
{
    if (x % 2 != 0)
    {
        return x;
    }
}

int evenOrOdd(int (*p_evenOrOdd[2])(int), int x)
{
    p_evenOrOdd[0] = isEven;
    p_evenOrOdd[1] = isOdd;
    if (p_evenOrOdd[0])
    {
        return p_evenOrOdd[0](x);
    }
    else
    {
        return p_evenOrOdd[1](x);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    result = evenOrOdd(isEven, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting `p_evenOrOdd[0]/[1]` in the function? It is supposed to take these as parameters. That is an array of *two* functions. But you are passing it only one.

Comment: Both functions: not all control paths return a value. Is this an exercise in function pointers, or a solution to finding whether a number is odd or even? The whole thing is quite strange.

Comment: What it means is that your function expects an array of 2 pointers to function and you're passing in a pointer to function, which is like completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> : "warning: passing argument 1 of 'evenOrOdd' from incompatible pointer type"

`int (*p_evenOrOdd[2])(int)`, as a function parameter to `evenOrOdd()`, is a pointer to a function pointer.

`isEven`, when passed in  `evenOrOdd(isEven, 10)`, is a function pointer.

A pointer to a function pointer is incompatible with a function pointer.

---

I suspect OP wants the following but the rest of the function goal is unclear.

```
// int evenOrOdd(int (*p_evenOrOdd[2])(int), int x)
int evenOrOdd(int (*p_evenOrOdd)(int), int x)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Now, I understand this. I have just created a new array of function pointer in main function and THIS has added as an argument of function